# htaccess rewrite root to file with varaible

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I've found a good amount of tutorials on .htaccess files and was able to get something close:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^HERE/(.*)$ /page1.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Now this lets me do 
www.domain.com/HERE/35
but i want to do
www.domain.com/35
I only want this to work for the root and not folder roots
When i remove the "**HERE**" it shows missing file 404.

I will still need the variable to be pass through.

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a few conditions, and possibly make your regex a bit more restrictive:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /page1.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```